# Can a google script run without logging in?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'd like a script to run when my gmail receives a specific attachment. There appear to be examples of such scripts but my requirement is for the script to execute without having to log in to gmail. Specifically, once the script has been set up, I expect that it should be triggered thereafter whenever the attachment arrives. The action it performs would be to post the file to my web server where I would process it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a trigger for when Gmail receives an email (with or without an attachment).

What you could do is have a script with a time based trigger check to see if an email had been received that meets certain requirements -- like has a particular attachment.

You would need to have the script mark it in some way to avoid processing it repeatedly. I would likely apply a label to indicate it had been processed.

This will get you started:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_time_triggers